# python dataframe boolean values with if statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

i wanna make if statement to show all **REF_INT** that are duplicated i tried this:

```
(df_picru['REF_INT'].value_counts()==1)
```

and it shows me all values with true or false but i dont wanna do something like this:

```
if (df_picru['REF_INT'].value_counts()==1)
print "df_picru['REF_INT']"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using groupby.

```
#groupby REF_INT and then count the occurrence and set as duplicate if count is greater than 1
df_picru.groupby('REF_INT').apply(lambda x: 'Duplicated' if len(x)> 1 else 'Unique')
Out[21]: 
REF_INT
1        Unique
2    Duplicated
3        Unique
8    Duplicated
dtype: object
```

value_counts can actually work if you make a minor change:

```
df_picru.REF_INT.value_counts()[lambda x: x>1]
Out[31]: 
2    2
8    2
Name: REF_INT, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [28]: df_picru['new'] = \
             df_picru['REF_INT'].duplicated(keep=False) \
                     .map({True:'duplicates',False:'unique'})

In [29]: df_picru
Out[29]:
   REF_INT         new
0        1      unique
1        2  duplicates
2        3      unique
3        8  duplicates
4        8  duplicates
5        2  duplicates
```

Comment: i wanted to see only if there is any value duplicated because i have a lot of data and when i applied this it didnt show me all columns.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for boolean mask and for new column [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df_picru['REF_INT'].duplicated(keep=False)
```

Sample:

```
df_picru = pd.DataFrame({'REF_INT':[1,2,3,8,8,2]})

mask = df_picru['REF_INT'].duplicated(keep=False)
print (mask)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: REF_INT, dtype: bool

df_picru['new'] = np.where(mask, 'duplicates', 'unique')
print (df_picru)
   REF_INT         new
0        1      unique
1        2  duplicates
2        3      unique
3        8  duplicates
4        8  duplicates
5        2  duplicates
```

If need check at least one if `unique` value need [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) for convert `boolean mask` - `array` to scalar `True` or `False`:

```
if mask.any():
    print ('at least one unique')
at least one unique
```

Comment: thank you @jezrael. i was looking for at least one duplicated because i wanted to know if there is any value duplicated in my column.